# Algorithms/Data Structures Interview

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The objective is to convert an array like `a3b5c2` to `aaabbbbbcc` in-place.
I have a solution:

- Assuming that the array is of infinite size,
- I parse the array from    the end.
- look for a number (say n)
- depending on how many digits I get, I look for the next character.
- When I get it, I move the elements from current position through end of array by `n-1` positions.
- Fill the open positions with the encountered character.

The complexity of this solution will be O(n^2). Is there a solution with complexity less than O(n^2)?

Comment: There is an O(n) answer.

Comment: `array is of infinite size` If array size is infinite, how do you start from the end? :)

Comment: If you have an array of infinite size, maybe that computer is pretty valuable!

Comment: @KingsIndian I meant that you don't need to worry about the size! This works equally well if you parse from the beginning too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you parse the array once, you can know where the last element will be by summing all the numerical values.

Parse it once and find its final size.

Once you do that, start filling it from the "end" (from where its final value will be): 2 times `c`, then 5 times `b`...

This is a `O(n)` in-place solution.

**EDIT:**

As srbh.kmr said in comments, this won't work if the array has a series of badly-placed characters repeated only one time. For instance, if we have the array `a1b1c1d1e7`, the answer above will erase the last letters.

The only number that causes issues is `1`, and we can treat it in `O(n)`:

Before treating the array as explained above, eliminate those ones. Starting from the beginning, parse the array and each time a `1` is found, erase it and move the remaining letters forward (not the whole remaining array, just the next characters). If several `1`s are found in the array, the *hole* between the first and second parts of the array will get bigger. For the example array above, the steps look like this:

```
a1b1c1d1e7
// First parse gives length = 1+1+1+1+7

// Repair ones
a b1c1d1e7
ab 1c1d1e7
ab  c1d1e7
abc  1d1e7
abc   d1e7
abcd   1e7
abcd    e7
abcde    7
abcde7
```

*Then*, apply the algorithm above. If no number is found after a character, just copy the character to its position at the end of the array:

```
// Fill final array
abcde7    x
          ^ 11th position
abcde     e
abcde    ee
abcde   eee
abcde  eeee
abcde eeeee
abcdeeeeeee
abcdeeeeeee  // Here we overwrite the first "e"
abcdeeeeeee  // Then we see there are lone letters (4 times), so we leave them.
```

Comment: We could possibly be overwriting the information. Consider: `a1b7c2` Am I missing something here ?

Comment: I am assuming that when you say start filling from the end, you also mean that I parse from the current array's end.

Comment: @srbh.kmr Nice point. In your example it works, but it's out if luck! We can imagine something like `a1b1c1d1e7` and *that* would be problematic... It's the `1`s that cause this. I'm thinking about it...

Comment: @VaishakSuresh For the counting you can parse in any way. For the filling, yes, you have to start from the last letters of course.

Comment: You could just do the filling up for `n-1` times instead of replacing one character?

Comment: @VaishakSuresh That's what I did, I just illustrated each step, a step being one letter changes.

Comment: How is this O(n)? You parse n times, if 1 is encountered you move characters, then you start filling up.
I think this is > O(n) no?

Comment: You don't parse n times, you parse 3 times: 1 to count, 1 to erase ones, and 1 to fill the array.